# How do you properly get a response with cookies using flutter web only?

Tags: flutter

i am getting used to switch from flutter mobile to web.
Never having interacted with cookies on mobile, doing so now it's getting into my nerves.

Whenever i try to test for a response from a random website, to see if i can get their cookies, i get everything from the response except for the cookies (aka 'set-cookies' value).

Here's a snippet from the fetch i use:
[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfZ4d.png)

But i only get the following response:
[Response in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTseI.png)

I'm using a random website i found to test it ('https://catfact.ninja/fact'), i am not sure if that's important.

In case i am doing something wrong, is there any guide or something to set up android studio in order to get cookies or something else?

Already tried to use dart:html, dart:http, package:http, and dart:io packages.

**Edit:**

**Here's the main screen:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../data/repository/cookie_repository.dart';
import '../../domain/repository/interface/i_cookie_repository.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final ICookieRepository cookieRepository = CookieRepository();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<String>> getUiData() async {
    final List<String> cookies = await cookieRepository.getCookies();
    return cookies;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
          future: getUiData(),
          builder: (
            BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot,
          ) {
            //debugPrint("MAINSCREEN 1st SNAPSHOT:  $snapshot");
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              //debugPrint("MAINSCREEN HAS ERROR:  $snapshot");
              return const Text("HAS ERROR");
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              //debugPrint("MAINSCREEN HAS DATA:  $snapshot");
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                itemBuilder: (
                  BuildContext context,
                  int index,
                ) {
                  final payload = snapshot.data![index];
                  return Card(
                    child: Text(payload),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Text("IS EMPTY");
            } else {
              return const Text("OTHER ERROR");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Here is the data repository where i get the response:**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

import '../../domain/repository/interface/i_cookie_repository.dart';

class CookieRepository extends ICookieRepository {
  List<String> parsedCookieList = [];
  final String cookieUrl = "https://catfact.ninja/fact";

  @override
  Future<List<String>> getCookies() async {
    if (parsedCookieList.isEmpty) {
      fetchDataFromCookieOld();
      final cookie = await fetchDataFromCookie() ?? "";
      parsedCookieList = [cookie] ?? [];
    }
    return parsedCookieList;
  }

  Future<void> fetchDataFromCookieOld() async {
    final response = await Client().get(
      Uri.parse('https://catfact.ninja/fact'),
    );
    response.headers.forEach((key, value) => debugPrint('$key: $value'));
  }
```

Take in consideration that the code wasn't cleaned, so it looks horrible.

.....................................

Comment: Please don't repost identical questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490798/how-do-you-properly-get-a-response-with-cookies-using-flutter-web